# What's the user agent of Chrome for Android after the user switches it to desktop version?

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, user-agent, chrome-for-android

We know Chrome for Android's user agent is:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76B) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.133 Mobile Safari/535.19

We also know the latest version of Chrome for Android provided a new feature which allows users to manually switch their Chrome for Android to a desktop version via graphic user interface.

I wanna know the user agent of Chrome for Android after it's switched to desktop version by users.

Comment: I dont think Andorid has Safari as user agent.

Comment: Ok. It is actually.. Safari.. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After toggling the "Request desktop site" in the latest Chrome for Android, the User Agent is reported as:

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.45 Safari/535.19

For reference, this is the default Chrome User Agent on Android 4.1:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Galaxy Nexus Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19